<img> element not showing after <canvas> element
For some reason the <img> element is not showing.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.4/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.4/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div id="minimap">
        <canvas id="minimap-main"/>
        <img src="MiniMap.png" width="50px" height="50px" id="minimap-char">
      </div>
    </main>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

It works if I place the  element before the <canvas> element but then I can't overlay them which I need to do.

<canvas> isn’t a void tag – its contents are the fallback displayed when the user agent doesn’t have canvas support. You need </canvas>, or the <img> will be treated as a child of the canvas element.
<canvas id="minimap-main"></canvas>
<img src="MiniMap.png" width="50px" height="50px" id="minimap-char">

Remember to inspect the document tree with your browser’s developer tools to confirm that it’s what you expect, and validate your HTML.
